# How to render an image field

Tags: theming, entities

What is the correct way to render a Drupal 7 image field and show the default image if the field is empty?

If I use `field_get_items` it will simply return `FALSE` when the field is empty.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think best practice would probably be to use [`field_view_field()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_field/7):

```
$view = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_image');
print render($view);
```

That will render the field as if it was attached to an entity view, and as such will provide the default image if none is available.

Comment: As documented, you can either use the display settings from an existing view mode or provide your own as fourth argument. Also, if you only want the field value with its label and wrapper markup, use field_view_value().

Answer (score 10):

You can also image style (image cache presets in D6) like this:

```
render(field_view_field('user', $user, 'field_avatar', array('settings' => array('image_style' => 'avatar'))));
```

Comment: `render()` requires a variable passed as reference, and since `field_view_field()` doesn't return a reference, that code raises an error. See [Clive's answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/33057/199) to see how `render()` should be called.